# XeLaTeX, Texlipse, polyglossia german language issue

Tags: xetex, miktex, polyglossia, texlipse, eclipse

I'm trying to set up an Eclipse Environment with TexLipse using XeLaTex which is throwing the following error during "build":

```
xelatex.exe> ("C:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\polyglossia\gloss-german.ldf"
xelatex.exe> 
xelatex.exe> Package polyglossia Warning: \setlocalhyphenmin useless for unknown language ge
xelatex.exe> rman on input line 6.
xelatex.exe> Package polyglossia Warning: You asked for `ngerman' but only `german'    hyphenat
xelatex.exe> ion is available! on input line 57.
```

The Tex document look like this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setdefaultlanguage[spelling=new,latesthyphen=true,babelshorthands=true]{german}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

If I run XeLatex via command line everything works like a charm and a valid pdf is generated. But something doesn't work during the Eclipse TexLipse "build". The definition for the builder in Eclipse is set as `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --src-specials %input`

Exactly the same line can be used in the command line for a valid generation of a PDF file. 
Does anybody know what TexLipse is messing up? At least I'm suspecting it for the issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Surely you have to remove `--src-specials`, although it's probably not the source of the problem.

Comment: My feeling is that the command line and TeXlipse use different TeX distributions. Can you check for the path of `scrartcl.cls` in the `.log` file for the two compilations?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and the warm welcome here egreg.

The version via cmd for the scrartcl.cls seems to be `("C:\Program Files\MikTex\tex\latex\koma-script\scrartcl.cls"
Document Class: scrartcl 2013/12/19 v3.12 KOMA-Script document class (article)` which is exactly the same as via texlipse. For both runs the --src-specials was removed.

Comment: Here's the whole log file for the cmd line execution which is wokring [Log File](http://pastebin.com/6aH5yWxm) and here [Log File](http://pastebin.com/PP7rb7R7) at line 461 the error occurs. Maybe this helpful.

Comment: If you look at the start, the log file with TeXlipse says `Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 0 languages loaded.` which becomes `Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 4 languages loaded.` from the command line. So you have a straw `xelatex.fmt` file somewhere that TeXlipse somehow picks up.

Comment: I've done a few tests building the pdf with different editors, such as Texmaker, TeXstuio and TeXnicCenter. All of theme worked flawlessly with the `xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode` invocation of xelatex. Therefore I suppose an error concerning TeXlipse and your hint with some internals in your last comment. Sadly that are inconvenient news for using my favorite IDE. Either I'll stick with it and build it via command line which makes the workflow pretty unhandy or I'll switch to some of the other editors and give them a try. Hopefully sometime there's a fix for that.

Comment: Did you search on your file system for files named `xelatex.fmt`?

Comment: Yes I did and I found it located at "...\MikTex\miktex\data\le\xetex\xelatex.fmt" but don't know what to do with it. It's not readable.

Comment: Just that one? There should be two.

Comment: No there's no more. I don't understand why every other build is working or in other words what TeXlipse does mess up.

Comment: Sorry, but that's all I can suggest: the log file clearly shows that TeXlipse is using a different format. Try adding the `-recorder` option to the invocation and look at the generated `.fls` file with the two compilations: the format used should be on the fourth line.

Comment: You have two different formats. One can see it at the dates. Does texclipse runs with different rights/user settings and so picking the format from another user? If you can run a command from inside texclipse you can also use `kpsewhich -engine=xetex xelatex.fmt` to identify the location.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the issue that lead to the problem with your great hints and possible solutions. Thanks for that guys!

Miktex somehow installed some packages e.g. xelatex.fmt in `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\...` directory. This could be arisen from my own fault in the previous installation procedure. Miktex asks for user confirmation to install new missing packages. I probably selected "install for user" and not "install for all users" which led to this situation. When I invoked xelatex from cmd there was no issue occurring because it could find the package in the user directory. Somehow texlipse didn't find it. The reason for that in detail is not clear to me.

I recognized the problem because of your hints to look at the `-recorder` option and the created `.fls` file, within different paths were used for the xelatex.fmt file.

To solve the problem I simply deinstalled miktex and reinstalled it for all users - the same I did before. But this time I took care not selecting "install for user" during the package installation of the other missing packages while invoking the first xelatex run. Now there are no files, except some temp files, in the users home directory and everything works perfectly.

Some further hint which could cause access exceptions: I had to grand my user full privileges on the `Programm Files\Miktex\` folder to get rid of it. (Maybe this is helpful for other problems too).

So thanks again for your quick help and great tips. I appreciate it very much.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.